# How to center only some elements in an HTML table?

Tags: html, html-table

I have a simple HTML table which one cell which is centered:

```html
<table width=100%>
   <tr>
      <td align=center>
          <p>Element1 (Centered)</p>
          <p>Element2 (Centered)</p>
          <p>Element3 (Should be on the left)</p>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How can I have only Element1 and 2 centered while Element3 is aligned on the left ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.align-left {
  text-align: left;
}

.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table width=100%>
   <tr>
      <td class="align-center">
          <p>Element1 (Centered)</p>
          <p>Element2 (Centered)</p>
          <p class="align-left">Element3 (Should be on the left)</p>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Please note, what [`align` attribute is **deprecated**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2). Use `text-align` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this :

```css
.center
{
    text-align: center;
}

td > p:nth-child(3)
{
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table width=100%>
   <tr>
      <td class="center">
          <p>Element1 (Centered)</p>
          <p>Element2 (Centered)</p>
          <p>Element3 (Should be on the left)</p>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Note that align attribute is [deprecated](https://www.w3resource.com/html/attributes/html-align-attribute.php) from HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Simple use class with `text-align:left;`

```css
.left{
text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<table width=100%>
   <tr>
      <td align=center>
          <p>Element1 (Centered)</p>
          <p>Element2 (Centered)</p>
          <p class='left'>Element3 (Should be on the left)</p>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table width=100%>
   <tr>
      <td>
          <p align=center>Element1 (Centered)</p>
          <p align=center>Element2 (Centered)</p>
          <p align=left>Element3 (Should be on the left)</p>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Set the `align` attributes to the paragraphs instead.

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <style>
      td p:last-child {
          text-align: left;
      }
    </style>
    <table width=100%>
       <tr>
          <td align=center>
              <p>Element1 (Centered)</p>
              <p>Element2 (Centered)</p>
              <p>Element3 (Should be on the left)</p>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

or if you need to set the style for particular child use that with the number of the child instead of `3` in parentheses:

```html
<style>
      td p:nth-child(3) {
          text-align: left;
      }
    </style>
    <table width=100%>
       <tr>
          <td align=center>
              <p>Element1 (Centered)</p>
              <p>Element2 (Centered)</p>
              <p>Element3 (Should be on the left)</p>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```